# "C'est du mauvais français" du vs de ?

Tags: grammaire, articles, partitif

Another user pointed out some poor phrasing in a French sentence I had linked to by saying "C'est du mauvais français."

I am not sure why this uses *du* rather than *de*; my impression was that the adjective would cause you to use *de*. I still oftentimes confuse the proper usage of *de*/*du*/*de la*/*de l'*/*des* in cases like this one.

Comment: Je soupçonne que c'est le résultat du construction «être de» qui indique le qualité de membre d'un groupe, en ce cas le groupe des mots qui constitue «le français»?  Voir  2.I.B.6.c de http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/être

Comment: An adjective can only cause you to use "de" instead of "des," not instead of "du" or "de la."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct usage would be "C'est du mauvais français", not "de".
"français" is here used as something quantifiable and definite (de le => du français, de la langue française, des mots en français, that you can touch and split like du pain), not something abstract like an adverb describing a manner (e.g. c'est de bonne heure = it's early, c'est de bonne guerre = it's fair enough)

Distinction is made (sometimes not easily) between the quantifyable noun and the abstract notion as an adverb. Example given, "c'est de bonne guerre" meaning it's only fair, and "c'est de la bonne guerre" meaning this is some good war.

You are not constrained to use "de" with an adjective + noun, but more often with the adverbial clause.

Answer (score 4):

> Le français = la langue française. (l'anglais = la langue anglaise).

this is **singular** => du (bon / mauvais) français = de la (bonne / mauvaise) langue française.

- masculin + singulier + indéfini => **du** or **un**
- féminin + singulier + indéfini => **de la** or **une**
- masculin / féminin + pluriel + indéfini => **de** ou **des**

du/de la/de = partitif/indénombrable (matière, liquide): du lait, de bons sentiments.

> de mauvais français = de mauvaises personnes françaises.

On dirait *ce sont de mauvais français* (pluriel => ce sont)

Comment: Surely it would be _ce sont **des** mauvais français_  ?

Comment: @Micromégas both are equal. "de" is more stylish.

Answer (score 1):

It's a rule in French, the construct "de le" doesn't exist and is replaced by "du". As opposed to the feminine for which it is "de la".

> Je mange de la glace. *I eat ice cream*
>
> Je mange du pain *I eat bread*
>
> Je me souviens de la mer. *I remember the sea*
>
> Je parle du français. *I'm talking about French*

Comment: Yes, this is not the point of the question~ I know *de le* contracts to *du*. I am asking why *le* is present at all, why we are saying *du mauvais français* rather than *de mauvais français*, as you might when saying *J'ai plus d'argent.* But thank you anyway.